# duplicity list files

Tags: files, format, duplicity

I have backed up files in /media/sdb1/mybkup

I ask duplicity to list the backed up files.
Tried several formats based on ask ubuntu answers

duplicity list-current-files /media/sdb1/mybkup

duplicity list-current-files files:///media/sdb1/mybkup

What is the correct format to list backed up files in /media/sdb1/mybkup

Comment: I have limited experience using duplicity directly in the command line, but when I tried using it with an invalid URL I got the following output.

Bad URL '/home/marcus/Downloads'.
Examples of URL strings are "scp://user@host.net:1234/path" and
"file:///usr/local".  See the man page for more information.

So it appears the correct syntax would be:

duplicity list-current-files files:///media/sdb1/mybkup

If the backups are encrypted you may need to use additional commands to pass the password to duplicity.  Just kinda guessing here.

Comment: What happens exactly? Please [edit] to clarify, including any error messages, in full.

Comment: You might just need to switch `files:` for `file:`

Answer (score 1):

[duplicity man page](https://duplicity.nongnu.org/vers8/duplicity.1.html) states

```
duplicity list-current-files [options] [--time time] target_url
```

and for local file backends (section URL Format)

```
Local file path
file://[relative|/absolute]/local/path
```

so

```
duplicity list-current-files file:///media/sdb1/mybkup
```

should work fine. doesn't it? ..ede/duply.net

Comment: I do it like this: `duplicity list-current-files file:/media/[share]/[directory1]/[directory2]` .  I don't know if the additional /'s are required.